# Connecting to LDAP with MD5 password

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, md5

I have this settings to connect to my LDAP :

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://urlTomyLDAP:389");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, name);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
```

When password is in "clear" all works fine. But this password is get from web client and it is hash (with JavaScript).
So I don't have the password in clear.
Is it possible to configure environment map with my hashed password ? And how ?

Comment: This is not possible, since the ldap requires the password in plain text (not hashed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible and it would be wrong to do so.

Hashes are used to protect clear-text password from being revealed if they get accessed (e.g. by an admin) or stolen. Therefore LDAP normally stores a hash of user's password. If someone gets access to the stored LDAP password hash, original user's password is not visible so it cannot be used to authenticate.

If you would accept password's hash as a valid authentication method, then getting access to the hash would enable someone to authenticate without knowing original password.

If you absolutely need authentication done within a browser, then it would be safer to deliver password's hash from LDAP to client and validate user's input against the received hash by JavaScript. In such case salt is an absolute must and this is really not the way you should implement security.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't understand hashing as the operation.
When you hash string, you cannot convert it back.

Only thing that makes sense with hashing is to **compare** it with another hashed string. If both hashed strings are same - you can conclude that both pre-hashed string are the same (equal).

For your particular situation - you should leave hashing as security measure since you won't be able to login with hashed password.

If you want to know more - check [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Hashing#Passwords) out.